# DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My query is here. If i gives id manually everyhting is perfect. But programaticaly gives me below error.
Anyone help me for this ?

```
with recursive cte as ( select *, 1 as depth from e_categories where id=? union all select p.*, cte.depth+1 as depth from e_categories p inner join cte on p.parent = cte.title WHERE depth < 3 ) select * from cte;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]